# How to remove Ubuntu Pro from a machine?

Tags: apt, administration

What is the process to stop using Ubuntu Pro and return the machine to what would have been it's general configuration before using Ubuntu Pro?

I've done "sudo pro detach" which said it removed it and I've checked in my Ubuntu One account.

```
mark@science2:/etc/apt$ sudo  pro status
SERVICE          AVAILABLE  DESCRIPTION
anbox-cloud      yes        Scalable Android in the cloud
esm-apps         yes        Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes        Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
livepatch        yes        Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel  yes        Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
usg              yes        Security compliance and audit tools

For a list of all Ubuntu Pro services, run 'pro status --all'

This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Pro subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/pro
mark@science2:/etc/apt$
```

However sudo apt update appears to show stuff still hanging around:

```
mark@science2:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                           
Hit:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                    
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                   
Hit:6 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                       
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                 
Get:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease [7,553 B]                    
Err:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease           
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AB01A101DB53907B
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/heyarje/makemkv-beta/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                              
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AB01A101DB53907B
W: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/dists/jammy-apps-security/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AB01A101DB53907B
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
mark@science2:/etc/apt$
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: My understanding is the detach option will remove the "pro token" from your computer. Apparently it does not remove the esm repository. This is why you see the error.  Detach won't uninstall any security fixes it has already installed, if that's what you mean by "return to general configuration". If the error bothers you, you can remove the offending repository manually.

Comment: Is this just the esm-apps-sources.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d ?

I also found a '20apt-esm-hook.conf file in apt.conf.d as well as stuff in /var/lib  so I'm unsure of what happens if there are old files hanging around when I update.

My goal is to upgrade to 23.10 as the Pro subscription has caused a couple of problems that the KDE guys won't look at due to the revisions being too old.

Comment: I can't tell you what will happen as I never did it. You can move the file from `etc/apt/sources.list.d` somewhere safe and see if that is sufficient.

Comment: It appears to have been safe. Apt update now appears to look at the correct entries and acts reasonable. and I was able to upgrade from 220.04 LTS to 23.04.

The issues I am left to right now are:

1) I have 4 files held back. I do not know if that's a problem caused by removing Ubuntu Pro or just some normal reason. I'll wait a few days to see if that resolves itself.

2) neofetch returns strange results - It shows a 6.2 kernel and Plasma 5.27.4, both of which I think are 23.04, but in says the machine is still Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

Comment: I hope that if and when the files being held back are updated that I can move on to 23.10. Will wait and see.