# How to remove Ubuntu Pro Subscription Activation from machine

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed Ubuntu in my VM using VBox, and accidentally activated Ubuntu Pro Subscription on 2 machines. How do I remove the unwanted machine from the Ubuntu Pro Subscription?

Comment: This [unanswered question on AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489122/how-to-remove-ubuntu-pro-from-a-machine) suggests using `sudo pro detach`

Comment: You tagged Ubuntu v14.04 - was that intentional?

Comment: I think I've added it by mistake.

Comment: then what is your version< you can edit the tag